# SwiftUI, how to change View (don't use button) color when pressing?

Tags: ios, swiftui

As the title, it's a typical use case. And it's easy to achieve if using SwiftUI `buttonStyle`.
But for some reason I cannot use `Button`. So, how to do it with `View`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [onTapGesture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ontapgesture(count:perform:)) modifier for your view

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var color = Color.green

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .padding()
            .background(color)
            .onTapGesture {
                color = Color.blue
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am using `highPriorityGesture`. It has conflict with other gesture modifier.

Comment: @iaomw can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?